# Batch import to pio EventServer via REST API

Tags: predictionio

I need import pregenerated CSV/JSON text file as one batch into predictionio eventservet with curl rest api call with post request method. Exists similar operation in **`pio`** as bulk in `ElasticSearch`? How can I find batch format description or more info about this topic?

In python exists `batch import` and I need to execute similar process with post `curl` call. Size of one file is 8MB and format is `.json` or `.csv` file.

Comment: You may also want to ask on this forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/predictionio-user

Answer (score 1):

As of PredictionIO 0.9.5 it is possible to import up to 50 events at a time, via REST:
https://docs.prediction.io/datacollection/eventmodel/#3.-batch-events-to-the-eventserver

Basically: combine the events into a JSON array and send them to `/batch/events.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Create JSON **exactly** like these. One event per newline so they can be read in parallel one line at a time. Any type of event can be imported this way, note the eventTime field must be in each as an ISO 8601 date.

https://docs.prediction.io/datacollection/batchimport/

Comment: only first item from batch collection is added in this case

Comment: please share the json body in the request and the URL you are using, also you must have pio v0.9.5+